# Best way to create n number of arrays holding objects

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist

A little stuck and any input would be much appreciated. 
The rundown: 
I have an ArrayList of strings.
I have a for loop iterating through said ArrayList.
When the loop begins it creates an ArrayList (Let's call it list1).
If string criteria are not met (.match is false) then it puts the current element in the previously created ArrayList. (list1)
If string criteria are met in the current element (.match is true) it creates a new ArrayList. (Let's call it list2)
If the next string does not meet criteria (.match is true) it will put that element into the previously created ArrayList (list2)

This keeps looping creating an ArrayList if criteria are not met and putting the element into the previously created ArrayList if criteria are met. It does this until the for loop has ended.
Notes:
Newly created ArrayLists will be holding objects based on the current string element, for the simplicity of trying to explain it I left that part out.
As I have never dynamically created ArrayLists I'm lost on how to do this. Keep in mind I am not just asking how to dynamically create an ArrayList because I know that, that question has been answered on here.

 Please ask if you need any part of this clarified I have the programmer mindset where it makes total sense in my head but is hard to explain in layman's terms. 
General code example:

```
for(int i=0; i<fileList.size(); i++) {
        ArrayList <question> list1= new ArrayList <question> ();

        if(fileList.get(i).matches("^[|]+[|]+[|]+[1-9]+")) {
            ArrayList <question> listN= new ArrayList <question> ();
        }
        else
            currentArray.add(fileList.get(i)); //CurrentArray is what ever the last created ArrayList is
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to have an ArrayList<ArrayList<question>> which you add your new ArrayLists to.

Comment: Before for loop: `ArrayList<Question> currentArrayList = new ArrayList<Question>();`
In for loop: `if(..match..) {currentArrayList = new ArrayList<Question>();} else {currentArrayList.add(...);} `

Comment: Just spent like 30min typing that up please don't tell me it's that simple. lmao thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Question>> lists= new ArrayList<>();
lists.add(new ArrayList<Question>());        

for(int i=0; i<fileList.size(); i++) {

    if(fileList.get(i).matches("^[|]+[|]+[|]+[1-9]+")) {
         lists.add(new ArrayList<Question>());
    } else {
        lists.get(lists.size() - 1).add(fileList.get(i));
    }

}
```

I have supposed Question was an object, you can replace it by String if not. The idea as mentioned in the comments is to build your list of "list of questions" before the loop. So you could use it after. Also if the first item in fileList always match then you don't need to create a list before entering the loop.